# PHP Uncaught error - preventing MySQL Injection

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am getting the following error

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magic/client/edit-client.php:102 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magic/client/edit-client.php on line 102`

Please see code below for line 102 and its surrounding

```
 $stmt = $link->prepare("UPDATE users SET password = ?, notes = ?, url = ?, services = ?, status = ?, invoice = ?, pin = ?, agent_notes = ?, email = ?, phone = ?, WHERE id = ?");
  $stmt->bind_param("ssssssissii", trim($_POST['password']), trim($_POST['notes']), trim($_POST['url']), trim($_POST['services']), trim($_POST['status']), trim($_POST['invoice']), trim($_POST['pin']), trim($_POST['agent_notes']), trim($_POST['email']), trim($_POST['phone']), $_SESSION['client_id']);
```

I am not going to lie, the whole `$stmt->bind_param("ssssssissii"` is confusing me too, I get string and integer, but I am not sure if I am assuming this correctly:

If the input contains **text & numbers** then it should be `s` if it is **only** numbers, then it should be `i` - is this not correct?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: `phone = ?,` < that trailing comma shouldn't be there.

Comment: The error suggests that the problem isn't when binding parameters, but when preparing the query.  What is the error message from the database?  (Possibly in `$link->error` or similar?)  Never assume, always check the actual error.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - removed, now getting this `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_SESSION' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ')' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magic/client/edit-client.php on line 102`

Comment: @David - where do I find the error from the database ?

Comment: @Tom: If this is mysqli, check `$link->error`.  As for the new error you're getting, double-check your PHP syntax.

Comment: Fixed Thank you @FunkFortyNiner - removed the wrong `,` Thank you!!

Comment: Sure thing, glad I could be of help.

Comment: If you are getting confused due to the way mysqli works with prepared statements, try switching to PDO. IT is much simpler and offers for options. I would even recommend to use the wrapper class [EasyDB by Paragonie](https://github.com/paragonie/easydb)

Answer (score 0):

`phone = ?,` < that trailing comma shouldn't be there.

Thank you to @FunkFortyNinefor the answer.

Comment: Shouldn't that be the answer by @FunkFortyNiner explaining why the trailing comma in SQL breaks syntax, as opposed to PHP happily accepting trailing comma in most contexts?